# in R, reshaping a "mixed" data frame using melt and cast

Tags: r, casting, scatter-plot, melt

I would like to plot two types of values against each other (dupl and orig). Is it possible to easily reshape the following data frame

```
record=c("r1","r1","r2","r3","r3")
v1=rep(0,5)
v2=c(0,0,1,0,0)
v3=c(1,1,0,1,1)
type=c("orig","dupl","orig","orig","dupl")

df<-data.frame(record, v1, v2, v3, type)
df
  record v1 v2 v3 type
1     r1  0  0  1 orig
2     r1  0  0  1 dupl
3     r2  0  1  0 orig
4     r3  0  0  1 orig
5     r3  0  0  1 dupl
```

to look like this?

```
record  v1.orig v2.orig v3.orig v1.dupl v2.dupl v3.dupl
r1         0       0       1       0       0       1
r2         0       1       0            
r3         0       0       0       0       0       0
```

The point being so that I can make a plot of vX.orig vs vX.dupl. Or is there a better way to do this?
I am looking at dcast() but can't seem to get what I want, possibly because my data is only partially molten (along type?).

EDIT: here is what I've tried:

```
df1<-melt(df,id="record")
dcast(df1,record~value, margins=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do it like this:

```
library(reshape2)
melted <- melt(df, id.vars= c("record", "type"))
dcast(melted,  record ~ variable + type)

  record v1_dupl v1_orig v2_dupl v2_orig v3_dupl v3_orig
1     r1       0       0       0       0       1       1
2     r2      NA       0      NA       1      NA       0
3     r3       0       0       0       0       1       1
```

or my original answer:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% gather(vx, num, -record, -type) %>%
    unite(type, vx, type) %>%
    spread(type, num)
```

Comment: can this be generalized to columns that will not start with "v"? ...in my real scenario, I want all my columns (40) duplicated as "_dupl".

Comment: sure you can adjust that part to other `dplyr::select()` terms, check out the edit for an alternative using `reshape2`

Answer (score 2):

In base R, this is a straightforward reshape:

```
reshape(df, idvar="record", timevar="type", direction="wide")

#  record v1.orig v2.orig v3.orig v1.dupl v2.dupl v3.dupl
#1     r1       0       0       1       0       0       1
#3     r2       0       1       0      NA      NA      NA
#4     r3       0       0       1       0       0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `recast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
recast(df, record~variable + type)
#   record v1_dupl v1_orig v2_dupl v2_orig v3_dupl v3_orig
#1     r1       0       0       0       0       1       1
#2     r2      NA       0      NA       1      NA       0
#3     r3       0       0       0       0       1       1
```